# Press same button 3 times to turn on an LED

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistors, resistance

Is there a circuit that can turn on an LED by pressing the same button 3 times? I have tried to search the web but found none.

Comment: [Microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) are powerful but complex.  Research for more info.

Comment: What other features does it need?  How do you wish to reset, does the light turn off with a 4th press or a separate button?  What is your level of electronics skill?

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in learning about discrete electronics, you might want to build a 2-bit counter out of a pair of flip-flops, then put an AND gate on the output.

Counter starts at 00.  First button press and it goes to 01, second button press it goes to 10, third button press and it is 11...this turns on the AND gate.  One more press resets it.

Otherwise follow the other answer and have a microcontroller/Arduino/Raspberry Pi do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that would be with a microprocessor. You could do it with transistors or discrete logic, but with a small micro it would be easy. You would just need to interface the button to an input, the LED to an output, and write the code to detect and count button presses and turn the LED on when the count gets to three. You could also have it do different functions depending on how many times the button is pressed, like the flashlights that cycle through on, flashing, and off.

Comment: This'd be pretty easy with a 4017, too. No need for a micro.

Comment: @Hearth The thing about micro*controllers* is you can use the same part for all sorts of applications. No need to stock one chip for this, and a different chip for that. Changing the behaviour after the fact is also easier, requiring the substitution of a differently programmed chip, instead of complete redesign of the PCB. I'm all in favour of learning discrete digital logic, maybe using it for very simple behaviours, but it's worth knowing the pros and cons. (The main pro of digital logic is that you don't have to get out your computer and program it)

Comment: @Hearth what about resetting at power on, and resetting the count back to zero after the three presses? What about latching the LED on? That requires an extra gate, latch and peripheral passives that make an MCU solution much more attractive, at least to me.

Comment: @user253751, Re, "...requiring the substitution of a differently programmed chip..." Or not even that if you provide for in-circuit programming with Tag-Connect.